# How to replace an item in a column with an item from another column in R?

Tags: r

I am sure this is extremely simple but I cannot figure out how to do this in R.

There are two columns in the same data frame that I would like to manipulate and both of them contain characters. I want to write a line of code (or two) to replace the item in column 1 with the item from column 2 only if the item is present in column 2. If the item is not present in column 2, do not replace the item in column 1. I feel like I should be using `if_else` function but I am not sure what to put down that indicates the "presence" of the item?

Sample table below:

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Blue |  |
| Green | Blue |
| Red |  |
| Pink | Green |

Comment: Can you post sample data in `dput` **format**? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is a placeholder for the name of your dataset.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c("blue", "green", "red", "pink"), 
                 v2 = c(NA, "blue", NA, "green" ))

df$v1 <- ifelse(!is.na(df$v2), df$v2, df$v1)
```

In case, the empty values are not missing but empty strings use this:

```
df$v1 <- ifelse(df$v2 != ""), df$v2, df$v1)
```

For completeness only, in case you're unsure wether NAs and empty strings mix :

```
df$v1 <- ifelse(df$v2 != "" | !is.na(df$v2)), df$v2, df$v1)
```

Comment: Yes it does! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way with a logical index. The index `i` is `TRUE` if the value in the 2nd column is empty (no characters) or is missing (`NA`). Then negate that condition and assign in place.

```
i <- nchar(df1[[2]]) == 0 | is.na(df1[[2]])
df1[!i, 1] <- df1[!i, 2]

df1
#  Column.1 Column.2
#1     Blue         
#2     Blue     Blue
#3      Red         
#4    Green    Green
```

#### Data in `dput` format

```
df1 <-
structure(list(Column.1 = c("Blue", "Blue", "Red", "Green"), 
    Column.2 = c("", "Blue", "", "Green")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```